# Sending mail to a linux server

Tags: linux, unix

I know we can send an email from Linux server using a lot of commands, but is there a way to send an email to a Linux server? From an exchange account?

Comment: You’ll need to set up that server to accept incoming emails. It will involve setting up a FQDN, and mail software like Postfix.

Comment: I do get some emails there (like mail delivery failure) on the /home/mathb/mail path, does that mean a setup is already present?

Comment: Somewhat. you may need to check which software you have installed. You’ll also need to do more support to receive incoming emails at an address.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

- mail server accepting mail on the Linux server OR a Linux server to which mail is forwarded from a relay mail server.
- a user account configured on the Linux server with a mailbox

If those things are set up, then it's just a matter of sending an email to user@linix_hostname or user@forwarded_domain.